# Can't display product name, price,etc in productdetails

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

Good day,

I can't seem to display my productdetailspage. When I try to put the `product.name` or `product.price` in a `<p>` or `<h1>` it gives me the following err:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

What can cause this issue? Thank you in advance for your answers. I've tried to use the productcard component as well, but it displays : 'product' and not the actual name of the product

**ProductPage:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import products from '../data/products'
import Product from '../components/product'

function ProductPage(props){
    console.log(props.match.params.id)
    
    const product = products.find(product=> product.id === props.match.params.id)
   
    
    return(
        <div>
            <Nav/>
        <h1>product page</h1>
        {product.name}
        

  
        </div>  
    )
}

export default ProductPage
```

**ProductCard:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Products from '../data/products'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
function Product(props){
    function HandleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert('added to cart !')
        
    }
    return(
        
           <ul className="products">
   
            {Products.map(product=> (
            <li key={product.id} className="product">
                <img src={product.img}></img>
               <a href={"/product/:" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></a> 
                <p>price: €{product.price}</p>
                <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit}>
                <button>Add to cart</button> 
                </form>
                
                </li> 
                )
                
                )}
   
                 </ul>
       
    )
}
export default Product
```

**App.js :**

```
import React from 'react'

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './templates/home'
import Login from './templates/login'
import Store from './templates/store'
import ProductPage from './templates/productPage'
import Product from './components/product'



function App(){

  {document.title = 'Avesports'}

  return(
   
 
   
  <body>
   
         <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/store" component={Store}/>
        <Route path={"/product/:id" } component={ProductPage}/>

        </Switch>
  
      </Router>
 </body>
  
   
     
   
  )
}


export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that is `.find()` returned `undefined`, in order to handle you can do as:

```
<h1>product page</h1>
{product && product.name}
```

Or if you want to add a nice message in `null` or `undefined` case, you can handle as:

```
<h1>product page</h1>
{
  product ?
    product.name :
    <span>No product matched...</span>
}
```

Comment: fixed the err, but if i use {product && product.name} it returns undefined. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I hate myself!

when i was Linking the productpage i did this:

```
   <Link to={"/product/**:**" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></Link>
```

it should have been this:

```
<Link to={"/product/" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></Link>
```

i wasted 2 months trying fix the problem. And it was a type error all along.